# Blazor or Visual Studio error when assigning value to variable

Tags: visual-studio, blazor, intellisense

Not sure if I'm the only one seeing this in Visual Studio 2019 with Blazor. But if you set a variable and then assign a value to it later, it automatically enters the variable name after you enter the "=" sign.

```
private string _test;

_test =_test
```

Am I missing a VS setting? Not sure if this is unique to Blazor or VS2019.

Comment: Any update about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the culprit. By taking Perry's suggestion of toggling each Extension, I found the one that was causing the issue. Took quite awhile because I have a number of extensions.

It seems the **CSS Tools 2019** https://github.com/madskristensen/CssTools was the issue.

Confirmed it by turning it enable/disable a number of times. I now keep it disabled and have no issues.

Comment: Since you have a workaround about your issue, I suggest you could [mark your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/).

Answer (score 1):

**Actually**, I have not faced the same issue in my side.

So I doubt whether it is caused by your project itself, vs settings or vs extensions.

You could try the following steps to troubleshoot the issue:

**Suggestion**

**1)** disable any vs third party installed extensions under **Extensions**-->**Manage Extensions**-->**Installed** then restart VS to test it.

**2)** reset all vs settings under **Tools**-->**Import and Export Settings**-->**Reset all Settings**

**3)** close VS, delete `.vs` hidden folder under the solution folder, any `bin` and `obj` output folders and then restart your project.

[image]

**4)** [repair your VS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) or update it if there is a new version.

**Besides**, you can also provide a screenshot about presenting your issue.